# What does "move states away for" mean in this sentence?

Tags: phrases, expressions

I read a sentence: "His ambition, twinned with desperation, resonates with any teenager who wants to journey off to college or **move states away for** work, in a bid to escape youthful boundaries. "
Not sure what is the meaning of the phrase "move states away for". Does it mean quit working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"move states away for work" means picking up and move to a different state, far away from his birth state, for a job. "State" meaning another state in, likely, the United States. This is a teenager wanting to leave home to be far away from where he grew up, to find independence.

For example, say he grew up in Oregon, then moves to Minnesota (for a new job, college, etc.). Minnesota is many "states away" from Oregon.